# function doesn't read the object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

can some one please tell me how can i make the send function read the email object from the next code?

```
var email = {
    to: 'google@gmail.com',
    subject: 'new email',
    text: 'helloWorld'
}

function send() {
    var sendMe = new email();
    console.log(sendMe.subject);

}
send();​
```

i get this error i also tried to declare the email as follow :

```
var email = new object();
```

and it didn't work

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are either trying to do this:

```
var email = { to: 'google@gmail.com', subject: 'new email', text: 'helloWorld' }

function send()
{
    console.log(email.subject);
}

send();
```

Or this

```
function email()
{
    this.to = 'google@gmail.com';
    this.subject = 'new email';
    this.text = 'helloworld';
}

function send()
{
    var sendMe = new email();
    console.log(sendMe.subject);
}

send();
```

I'm not sure which, so I made an example of both. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want `sendMe` to point at the same data `email` is holding:

```
var email = { ...} ;
function send() {
   var sendMe = email;
   console.log(sendMe.subject);
}
```

But if this is the case, you might as well skip the extra variable and just use `email` directly:

```
var email = { ...} ;
function send() {
   console.log(email.subject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an identifier as an object constructor unless it's a function.

If you want a reference to the object that you created, just copy it from the variable:

```
var sendMe = email;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return object:

```
var email = function() {
    return {
        to: 'google@gmail.com',
        subject: 'new email',
        text: 'helloWorld'
    }
};
```

and then

```
function send() {
    var sendMe = new email();
    console.log(sendMe.subject);
}
```

should work.

Comment: This will work, but the 'new' keyword is useless in this case. Might as well just write `var sendMe = email();` since it's returning a new object

Comment: What's the difference? In you answer you use `this` which basically will do the same with `sendMe` - it will be same object as in mine. I only showed the way, it's not the perfect code :)

Comment: Yes it will result in the same object, but in your code the `new` keyword is not necessary since the object is being created inside the function anyway. Using the `new` keyword you are essentially creating two objects and returning one of them. It **will work** but is not optimal, that's all I'm saying

Comment: I've just copied & pasted that part of code from original, so `new` was incident ;)